# Wget problems using python subprocess

Tags: python, wget

I have a `url` that contains bunch of ampersands.
I also have a `cmd` given below

```
cmd = 'wget --verbose --auth-no-challenge --no-check-certificate -O res'
```

When I run the command using subprocess my url options after the first ampersand are not included in the actual query.

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(cmd + " " + url , shell=True)
```

What can I do to make sure that the entire url is passed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into similar issues with trying to figure out how to format the command for Popen.  Now I almost always use [shlex.split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) to do it for me.

Example from [python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
```

So for this particular example, you might have something like

```
>>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/somepage.html?foo=spam&bar=eggs&baz=ni'
>>> cmd = 'wget --verbose --auth-no-challenge --no-check-certificate -O res ' + url
>>> args = shlex.split(cmd)
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args)
>>> --2013-12-13 13:36:11--  http://www.example.com/somepage.html?foo=spam&bar=eggs&baz=ni
```

Answer (score 1):

try quoting the url using single quotes:

```
 url = "'what&ever&address'"
```